# HTML Help Workshop Crashes on Compiling a CHM

Tags: chm

Trying to build a CHM using Microsoft HTML Help Workshop. A soon as I click Compile, HTML Help Workshop states:

> An internal error has occurred. An error record has been saved to c:\os.err.

The only contents of the file are:

> ((Today's Date & Time))
>   Microsoft HTML Help Workshop Version 4.74.8702
>   HHA Version 4.74.8702
>   htmlproc.cpp(114) : Assertion failure: (pszTmp == m_pCompiler->m_pHtmlMem->psz)

The error only occurs for a few select, large projects, and happens from both the command line as well as the HTML Help Workshop GUI.

What causes this error to occur and how can I fix my project to run through the compiler?

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft HTML Help compiler has some unstated requirements for path name sizes.

Moving the project to a directory closer to the root drive (i.e. "C:\helpsystem\") and renaming folders inside the project to smaller name reduced the path name size enough so that the project would compile.

Answer (score 1):

I found Microsoft HTML Help Workshop to be a bit delicate to work with. Do you have all the prerequistes installed? Try running the compiler, hhc.exe, from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to watch out for is an Error 413 - Request Entity Too Large error.

I'm not sure how big is *too* big for HTML Help Workshop, but my htm file is a touch over 2MB, a large table, and it causes HTML Help Workshop to crash when processing it.

While this isn't the same problem, it was the hint I needed - [I'm not the first to find this on SO](https://superuser.com/questions/330418/file-size-limits-for-chm-html-help-format-files)..